# Get a particular string from a data using regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to get particular string from the data below.It is too long am here with sharing sample data. From this I have to get the `'france24Id=7GHYUFGty6fdGFHyy56'`
am not that much familier with regex.

How can I retreive  the string 'france24Id=7GHYUFGty6fdGFHyy56' from above data?

I tried splitting  the data using ',' but it is not an effective way.That's why I choose regex.

```
2016-07-29 12:08:46,260 s=xGuide, [xre-10-pipe@6da05f7a[,connection=WebSocketConnectionWrapper[/1.8.9]]] INFO  c=c.ore., - onConnect event payload={minimumVersion='0', applicationName='shell', fetl='555', authenticationToken='6y777', sessionAuthToken='', sessionGUID='null', connectURL='http://section?ruleName=Default', partnerId='hp', nativeDimensions=null, appParams={heartbeatRequest=1, france24Id=7GHYUFGty6fdGFHyy56, service=false, networkBuffer={min=150, max=150, step=0}}, deviceCaps={platform=Mac, receiverType=Native, revisions={protocol=1, auth=1, video=1}, pixelDimensions=[1280, 720]}, forceSource=null, reconnect=false, currentCommandIndex=0, reconnectReason=7, authService=9}
```

Comment: Do you care about the case where one of the quoted strings that you're not interested in (eg applicationName) coincidentally contains this same exact string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get what you want with `(france\d+Id)=([a-zA-Z0-9]+),`. This will grab your string and dump the two parts of it into platform-appropriate capture group variables (for instance, in Perl, `$1` and `$2` respectively).

In Java, your code would look a little like this:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public String matchID(String data) {
    Pattern r = new Pattern("(france\\d+Id)=([a-zA-Z0-9]+),");
    Matcher m = r.matcher(data);
    return m.group(2);
}
```

Comment: How can i do this with java

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "2016-07-29 12:08:46,260 s=xGuide, [xre-10-pipe@6da05f7a[,connection=WebSocketConnectionWrapper[/1.8.9]]] INFO  c=c.ore., - onConnect event payload={minimumVersion='0', applicationName='shell', fetl='555', authenticationToken='6y777', sessionAuthToken='', sessionGUID='null', connectURL='http://section?ruleName=Default', partnerId='hp', nativeDimensions=null, appParams={heartbeatRequest=1, france24Id=7GHYUFGty6fdGFHyy56, service=false, networkBuffer={min=150, max=150, step=0}}, deviceCaps={platform=Mac, receiverType=Native, revisions={protocol=1, auth=1, video=1}, pixelDimensions=[1280, 720]}, forceSource=null, reconnect=false, currentCommandIndex=0, reconnectReason=7, authService=9}";
    String regex = ".*(france24Id=[\\d|\\w]*),.*";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    if(matcher.matches()){
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this one:

```
String str = "france24Id=7GHYUFGty6fdGFHyy56";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=france24Id=)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("ID = " + matcher.group());
}
```

And the result is:

```
ID = 7GHYUFGty6fdGFHyy56
```

Comment: Look like this regex will match everything following "france24Id=", so you might want to use [a-zA-Z0-9] instead of '.'

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pattern and Matcher classes in Java.

```
String data = "2016-07-29 12:08:46,260 s=xGuide, [xre-10-pipe@6da05f7a[,connection=WebSocketConnectionWrapper[/1.8.9]]] INFO  c=c.ore., - onConnect event payload={minimumVersion='0', applicationName='shell', fetl='555', authenticationToken='6y777', sessionAuthToken='', sessionGUID='null', connectURL='http://section?ruleName=Default', partnerId='hp', nativeDimensions=null, appParams={heartbeatRequest=1, france24Id=7GHYUFGty6fdGFHyy56, service=false, networkBuffer={min=150, max=150, step=0}}, deviceCaps={platform=Mac, receiverType=Native, revisions={protocol=1, auth=1, video=1}, pixelDimensions=[1280, 720]}, forceSource=null, reconnect=false, currentCommandIndex=0, reconnectReason=7, authService=9}";   
 String regex1 = "france24Id=[a-zA-Z0-9]+"; //this matches france24Id=7GHYUFGty6fdGFHyy56
    String regex2 = "(?<=france24Id=)[a-zA-Z0-9]+"; //this matches 7GHYUFGty6fdGFHyy56 or whatever after "france24Id=" and before ','
    Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile(regex1);
    Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile(regex2);
    Matcher matcher1 = pattern1.matcher(data);
    Matcher matcher2 = pattern2.matcher(data);

    String result1, result2;

    if(matcher1.find())
        result1 = matcher1.group(); //if match is found, result1 should contain "france24Id=7GHYUFGty6fdGFHyy56"

    if(matcher2.find())
        result2 = matcher2.group(); //if match is found, result1 should contain "7GHYUFGty6fdGFHyy56"
```